# Include my "check if valid email" function in my AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

So now I have my successful code. But what I want to do is include this in my AJAX. So this is my AJAX:

```
function checkEmail() {
  // var myForm = $("#mainForm").serialize();
  var fname = $("#first").val();
  var lname = $("#second").val();
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var repass = $("#en").val();
  if (fname && lname && email && password && repass && password.length >= 6 && password == repass)) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "connection.php",
      data: {
          fname:fname,
          lname:lname,
          email:email,
          password:password,
          repass:repass
      },
      type: "POST",
      success:function(data){
  $("#emailExists").show();
  $("#email").css("border","2px solid green");
  $("#no").css("visibility","hidden");
  $("#yes").css("visibility","visible");
  if(data){
    $("#email").css("border", "2px solid red");
    $("#no").css("visibility","visible");
    $("#yes").css("visibility","hidden");
    }else
    {
    $("#email").css("border", "2px solid green");
    $("#no").css("visibility","hidden");
    $("#yes").css("visibility","visible");
    window.location.href = 'home.php';
    }
  $("#emailExists").html(data);
  },
  error:function (){
  }
  });
   }
}
```

So, what I want to do, is basically, in that if statement [if(name && lname...)]. In that particular section, I want to include this particular checking if email valid system too. So I was thinking maybe make this code (the if statement to check if email is valid), into a function, to then add it into the AJAX, so something like this:

```
if (fname && lname && email && password && repass && password.length >= 6 && password == repass && checkValidateEmail()) {
```

But if I keep that if statement in a function called checkValiateEmail() and do that, it isn't working. What should I do?

My Javascript for checking if email is valid:

```
  if(email.value === "") {
    no.style.visibility = 'visible';
    yes.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    email.style.border = '2px solid red';
    mailText.style.visibility = 'visible';
    mailText.innerText = "Please enter an email address.";
    validEmail.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  } else if (!validateEmail(email.value)) {
    no.style.visibility = 'visible';
    yes.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    email.style.border = '2px solid red';
    mailText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    validEmail.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    yes.style.visibility = 'visible';
    no.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    email.style.border = '2px solid green';
    mailText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    validEmail.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
```

validateEmail() function:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
  const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`validateEmail(email)` has exactly one parameter (the email that should be validated) but you are not passing any parameter in your if.

```js
if (fname && lname && email && password && repass && password.length >= 6 && password == repass && checkValidateEmail()) {
//                                                                                                                    ↑
//                                                         HERE the `email` is missing ───────────────────────────────┘
```

Your check has to be

```js
if ( /* ... */ validateEmail(email) ){
    // ...
}
```

otherwise there is nothing that can be checked. (Well, `undefined` is checked wheter it's a valid email, but of course it's not).

Comment: Ok, so remember that JS code, which checked if the email is valid or not, like the if statement. So, do we put all of that in one function called checkValidateEmail()?. Or do we use that validateEmail() function, which contained the REGEX?

Comment: No, use `validateEmail()`, that's the better choice.

Comment: Ok. I'll use validateEmail().

Comment: Hey, I used it. But what's happening is if, everything is correct, it should redirect to the homepage and the data should go to the database, but here, neither are happening. You could see for yourself in the AJAX code I posted in the question.

Comment: Check what `data` is containing in your success callback function. If that evaluates to false, e.g. because it is undefined or an empty string, your redirect is not executed.

Comment: I didn't understand. What would be the code?

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` after `success: function(data){` and before `if(data){`. Your fix probably is to remove the `if(data)`. Probably you don't have a `data`. But I don't know that. That can be tested with the `console.log(data)`.

Comment: Ok. This is what it says in the console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: validateEmail is not defined
    at checkEmail (script.js:8)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (login.php:648)

Comment: Well, there you go. `validateEmail()` is not defined. Maybe it's in a local scope? If you don't know what a scope is, read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Scope.

Comment: Okay. I changed it to a global scope, by adding it above the if statement. However, it still isn't working.

Comment: I suggest to read this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp and this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/debugging-tips-to-get-better-at-it/, this https://raygun.com/learn/javascript-debugging-tips (8, 9 and 10 especially) and maybe this https://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/debugging

Comment: I did. Still can't identify what's happening though.

Comment: Well, Stackoverflow helps you with debugging. What do expect me or others to do? My current information situation is "it still isn't working". Programming and especially debugging is mostly tracing errors back to their origin. You don't even give the error. Where should anyone who's willing to help (= e.g. me) start? You have to give error messages and context! You have to give me some code where I can click on "run" (or copy it to my local machine) and where I can see the error. That's not the case. I just can't help you because you neither give code nor errors.

Comment: Please create a code snippet (see here how this works: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/5934316) where I can **reproduce** the error. That's the minimal reproducable example I'm asking for all the time.

Comment: I did. I pasted the HTML and JS. You already have the AJAX.

Comment: Irrespective of debugging, do you notice anything wrong? Like do you have any reason in mind for why it isn't working?

Comment: Hello? You there?

Comment: Wait, the JS validation if statement code, and the AJAX are on two separate files. Does that matter? I've included that <script> in the login.php file though.

Comment: I'll vote for closing this question now. This is absolutely not a focused question. I told you three times to provide a [minmal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try to think out of the answerers perspective: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Give as few code as possible that produces your error. And give a one sentence question what you want to know. And google that question before! Stackoverflow is for supporting you in your work, not for doing your work.

Comment: I'm sorry. You may close the question now.

Comment: So, ok let me explain what I tried and what's happening. If I try this in the AJAX:   if (fname && lname && email && password && repass && password.length >= 6 && password == repass && validateEmail(email)) {, it's working perfectly fine. But if everything is correctly entered, it should redirect to the homepage, and the data should be inserted into the database, which isn't happening, but previously, without that "&& validateEmail(email)", it was happening.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function validateEmail(email) {
      const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return re.test(email);
    }

  if(email.value === "") {
    no.style.visibility = 'visible';
    yes.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    email.style.border = '2px solid red';
    mailText.style.visibility = 'visible';
    mailText.innerText = "Please enter an email address.";
    validEmail.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  } else if (!validateEmail(email.value)) {
    no.style.visibility = 'visible';
    yes.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    email.style.border = '2px solid red';
    mailText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    validEmail.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    yes.style.visibility = 'visible';
    no.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    email.style.border = '2px solid green';
    mailText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    validEmail.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input style="margin-left:-10px; width:505px; font-family:inherit; margin-top:11px" class="mail" type="text" id="email" name = "email" placeholder="Email Address">
     <i style="color: green; margin-top:28px; margin-left:-38px; position:absolute; visibility: hidden" class="fa fa-check-circle" id="yes"></i>
     <i style="color: red; margin-top:28px; margin-left:-38px; position:absolute; visibility: hidden" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" id="no"></i>
     <small style="margin-top:56px; position: fixed; margin-left: -498px; font-size: 14px; color:red; visibility: hidden" id="mailText"></small>
     <span style="margin-top:56px; position: fixed; margin-left: -498px; font-size: 14px; color: red; display:none" id="emailExists" name="emailExists" class="emailExists">Email address already taken.</span>
     <small style="margin-top:56px; position: fixed; margin-left: -498px; font-size: 14px; color:red; visibility:hidden" id="validEmail">Please enter a valid email address.</small>
```

```html
 <input style="margin-left:-10px; width:505px; font-family:inherit; margin-top:11px" class="mail" type="text" id="email" name = "email" placeholder="Email Address">
     <i style="color: green; margin-top:28px; margin-left:-38px; position:absolute; visibility: hidden" class="fa fa-check-circle" id="yes"></i>
     <i style="color: red; margin-top:28px; margin-left:-38px; position:absolute; visibility: hidden" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" id="no"></i>
     <small style="margin-top:56px; position: fixed; margin-left: -498px; font-size: 14px; color:red; visibility: hidden" id="mailText"></small>
     <span style="margin-top:56px; position: fixed; margin-left: -498px; font-size: 14px; color: red; display:none" id="emailExists" name="emailExists" class="emailExists">Email address already taken.</span>
     <small style="margin-top:56px; position: fixed; margin-left: -498px; font-size: 14px; color:red; visibility:hidden" id="validEmail">Please enter a valid email address.</small>
     
 <script type="text/javascript">  
    
    function validateEmail(email) {
      const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return re.test(email);
    }

  if(email.value === "") {
    no.style.visibility = 'visible';
    yes.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    email.style.border = '2px solid red';
    mailText.style.visibility = 'visible';
    mailText.innerText = "Please enter an email address.";
    validEmail.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  } else if (!validateEmail(email.value)) {
    no.style.visibility = 'visible';
    yes.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    email.style.border = '2px solid red';
    mailText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    validEmail.style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    yes.style.visibility = 'visible';
    no.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    email.style.border = '2px solid green';
    mailText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    validEmail.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  
 <script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).